# How to prove that $2^{2^{m}}-1 \equiv 0$ (mod $2^{2^{n}}+1$)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'd like to solve this problem but I can't

> $\exists \ m,n \ \in \mathbb{Z}$ & $ m\gt n\ge 0$
>
> $2^{2^{m}}-1 \equiv 0$ (mod $2^{2^{n}}+1$)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use $a^{2n}-1=(a^n-1)(a^n+1)$.

Comment: If the quantification really is just $\exists m,n$ then you could have just tried numbers until you found an example. The sensibly stronger form is $\forall m>0$, $\exists n$. Also, in regards to your comment to user121270, powers of two are "of the form $2n$" (i.e. they are even, which is all that matters), so you managed to miss the point he or she was making for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^{2^m}-1=(2^{2^{m-1}}-1)(2^{2^{m-1}}+1)$.

Then, not only there exists a pair $m,n$, but there are infinitely many, namely $m$ is any positive integer and $n=m-1$.

In fact, since $2^{2^{m-1}}-1$ can be factored again the same way (provided that $m>1$) the congruence is *always* true, given the conditions of the problem.

Comment: and can we say gcd(2^2^m+1,2^2^n+1) = 1 ?

Comment: Yes, since $2^{2^n}+1$ divides $2^{2^m}-1$, the remainder of the division $(2^{2^m}+1)/(2^{2^n}+1)$ is $2$ (this implies that the gcd divides $2$). But both numbers are odd. Then they are coprime.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $2^{2^m}-1$ is a difference of two squares if $m>0$.